# Script not allowed to access owned by someone else

Tags: php, linux, symfony1, installation, safe-mode

I have been trying to run the setup for the Siwapp app (an app based on the Symphony framework). And I keep getting this error once I specify the root Symphony folder.

`SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid/gid is 158807/158807 is not allowed to access /some/super/long/path owned by uid/gid 25000/25000`

How can I overcome this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go to shell, chown the whole directory with your user:group,this may solve the issue. In case you are on shared hosting, read cPanel, chances are you may not have shell, try FTP-ing using FileZilla and check file permissions as well. Safe mode restrictions, supposedly, make PHP scripts safe. This means, a script/resource owned by you can not be run/used by some other user/resource, you can not arbitrarily access resources, include files, open URLs, etc. Hopefully you have read this http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php and specially this http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php.